# Android menu not displaying

Tags: android, menu

My select_screen_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:id="@+id/home_menu"
      android:icon="@drawable/home_tab"
      android:title="Home" />
 <item android:id="@+id/submit_report"
      android:icon="@drawable/submit_tab"
      android:title="Submit a Report" />
  <item android:id="@+id/search_list"
      android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
      android:title="Search the List" />

</menu>
```

and my activity class used it as

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.select_screen_menu, menu);       
  return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home_menu: {
      Static.backwardTo(User.viewflipper,ConstandsUsed.USER_SELECT_SCREEN);
      return true;
    }
    case R.id.submit_report:
      Static.backwardTo(User.viewflipper, User.sumitAReport_PAGE);
      return true;
    case R.id.search_list:
      Static.backwardTo(User.viewflipper, User.searchTheList_PAGE);
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);      
  }
}
```

i have used the following code to identify the back button

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
---
---
}
```

this two are not working together. The menu will work only when this onkeydown function is removed.
Is there any way to use this together
Do I need to do any other things?

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Why are you not using the `@Override` annotation for your `onoptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`?

Comment: i used  @Override, i'm sorry for not showing it in my question

Comment: IMHO you don't need to identify the back button. The menu will close on it's own when you press it. The code should be working. Try to comment your `onKeyDown`. This might help.

Comment: actually i need that also, I need to identify the back button and dock down etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks and sorry to every one.  i understood my mistake actually i am always return true from the onkeydown function. when i change to return false if it is not the keycode that i need its work well

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(){
------
return true;
}
else
return false;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need write it in Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for considering me .  It is not working with me. Is there any importance of it order. Actually when i put the sysout statement in onkeydown function, I understood it reaching control over there when i press the menu

Comment: Is there any way for me to call the menu by code so that i can identify the menu press in onkeydown function and call by code  thanks